# convert very small double to a String

Tags: java, string, double, numbers

I have a very small number and I want to convert it to a String with the full number, not abbreviated in any way. I don't know how small this number can be.

for example, when I run:

```
double d = 1E-10;
System.out.println(d);
```

it shows `1.0E-10` instead of 0.000000001.

I've already tried `NumberFormat.getNumberInstance()` but it formats to `0`. and I don't know what expression to use on a `DecimalFormat` to work with any number.

Comment: But what do you want if it prints `1e-300`? 300 zeroes?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming that you want 500 zeroes in front of your number when you do:

```
double d = 1E-500;
```

then you can use:

```
double d = 1E-10;
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
System.out.println(nf.format(d));
```

Comment: FYI: The smallest double-precision number is ~ `5e-324`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that.

BTW, where did you get this number from?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_double_precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary64

Answer (score 3):

You can set the maximum and minimum number of digits in the fraction of a numberformatter with `setMinimumFractionDigits` and `setMaximumFractionDigits`. that should fix the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with BigDecimals in Java 5 using:

```
System.out.println(new java.math.BigDecimal(Double.toString(1E-10)).stripTrailingZeros().toPlainString());
```

Note that if you have the double value as a String in the first place, you would be better off using:

```
System.out.println(new java.math.BigDecimal("1E-10").toPlainString());
```

... as explained in the BigDecimal javadocs.

Answer (score -2):

Have a look at: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html#numberpattern

I think the format "0.####" might work.